# How to paste multiple commands output into single output file

Tags: linux, command-line, tail, head

I have txt file that I have to swap the first paragraph with last one. I did it but now I don't know how to paste everything in a new txt file.

This is my command

```
tail -14 gl.txt ; head -n 74 gl.txt | tail -n 68 ; head -5 gl.txt
```

I tried to use > like this

```
tail -14 gl.txt ; head -n 74 gl.txt | tail -n 68 ; head -5 gl.txt > gl_ok.txt
```

but it only takes the last paragraph.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to grouping the commands within `{ ...; }` and redirect the output at the end to a file:

```
{ tail -14 gl.txt ; head -n 74 gl.txt | tail -n 68 ; head -5 gl.txt; } > gl_ok.txt
```

note that the last semi-colon before close bracket is mandatory or group commands can be terminated with a newline like below:

```
{ tail -14 gl.txt ; head -n 74 gl.txt | tail -n 68 ; head -5 gl.txt
} > gl_ok.txt
```

if your shell is bash, see [man bash](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping) under "Compound Commands":

> { list; }
> list is simply executed in the current shell environment.  list must be terminated with  a  newline  or
> semicolon.  This is known as a *group command*.

see also grouping commands using sub-shell `( ... )` and you would do `(...) >output`